# Using xsltc.exe generated assembly in .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an XSLT stylesheet that I'm using via `XslCompiledTransform` as an assembly after compiling it using the `xsltc.exe` tool in the .NET SDK (so it's .NET 4.6.1).

I want to reuse it in a .NET Core 2.2 app but don't appear able to.
The [.NET Core 2.2 XslCompiledTransform.Load(Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.load?view=netcore-2.2#System_Xml_Xsl_XslCompiledTransform_Load_System_Type_) documentation clearly states you can use an assembly generated by `xsltc.exe` but has a note that I do not understand:

> You have to reference the XSLT assembly when compiling the code. For example,
>
> csc /r:system.dll;system.xml.dll;bookOrders.dll myCode.cs.

Is it possible to either recompile the xslt assembly in .NET Core 2.2 (but I cannot find an `xsltc.exe` in the .NET Core SDK so I'm guessing that's not a thing) or to reference my current assembly from .NET Core 2.2?

Or are both things a bad idea and there's a better way?

Update: It's now added as a reference but at runtime I get an exception for a missing file - `System.Data.SqlXml`. I can't figure out where to get that from now. I mean, I can see it in .NET 4.6.1 folders but how do I reference that from my .NET Core app?

There is another question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881887/xslcompiledtransform-loadtype-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-s?rq=1) but it is not yet resolved.

Comment: add it as a `Reference` in your csproj

Comment: @DanielA.White I did that and it didn't work and then I reloaded the project and the file reference worked! However, now I have an issue with a missing reference that i have updated my question with.