# Use xsltc.exe generated assembly (XSLT stylesheet) in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core, xslt

I have an XSLT stylesheet "Stylesheet.xsl" that i have compiled to a "Stylesheet.dll" using xsltc.exe

That DLL is included in my .NET 6 (`<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`) project and is used as follows:

```cs
var xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslCompiledTransform.Load(typeof(Stylesheet));
// ↑ System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

xslCompiledTransform.Transform(@"..\..\..\input.xml", @"..\..\..\output.xml");
```

The `Load` method throws an `FileNotFoundException` with message "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified."

The [documentation on xsltc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-compiler-xsltc-exe) says the following:

> Script blocks are supported only in .NET Framework. They are *not* supported on .NET Core or .NET 5 or later.

This heavily imiplies that stylesheets compiled using xsltc.exe should work on .NET Core or .NET 5 or later (when no script blocks are use) but they don't in my test.

Does anyone know why stylesheets compiled using xsltc.exe do not work with .NET 6 and how to fix this?

---

### More details

I've added more details on what I tried below.

---

Note that the stylesheet `Stylesheet.xsl` I use is very basic and uses no special functionality:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:for-each select="input/book">
                <booktitle>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </booktitle>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Command for generating the DLL:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\xsltc.exe" Stylesheet.xsl
```

Referencing the DLL in the SDK-style .csproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Stylesheet">
    <HintPath>.\Stylesheet.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

`input.xml`:

```
<input>
  <book title="First Title" />
  <book title="Second Title" />
</input>
```

`output.xml` when executing the transformation with the non-compiled stylesheet:

```
<output>
  <booktitle>First Title</booktitle>
  <booktitle>Second Title</booktitle>
</output>
```

---

I have researched and found other people having the same problem but haven't found a solution or an explanation on why the Microsoft Docs implicitly state it should work while it does not in my test.

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68129
- [Using xsltc.exe generated assembly in .NET Core 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55831139/19540924)
- [XslCompiledTransform.Load(type) : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlXml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51881887/19540924)

---

Stack trace of the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`:

```
   at System.Delegate.BindToMethodInfo(Object target, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType methodType, DelegateBindingFlags flags)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CreateDelegateInternal(Type delegateType, Object firstArgument, DelegateBindingFlags bindingFlags)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(MethodInfo executeMethod, Byte[] queryData, Type[] earlyBoundTypes)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(Type compiledStylesheet)
   at TestXslDotnet6.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\UserNameRedacted\Path\To\Repo\TestXslDotnet6\TestXslDotnet6\Program.cs:line 10
```

Comment: The obvious explanation would be that using a compiled spreadsheet requires an assembly that isn't available on the system you're running it on! Have you attempted to find this assembly and make it available?

Comment: That DLL seems to be part of SQL Server. I'm not sure why it's required for this. Does your stylesheet reference anything that's SQL Server-specific?

Comment: @AnnL. The assembly is available on my system as using the compiled spreadsheets with .NET Framework works. When using the compiled spreadsheets with .NET 6, this error appears. That would not be very surprising, but it is surprising as the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-compiler-xsltc-exe) imply that it should work on .NET Core or .NET 5 or later, but it does not in my test...

Comment: @AnnL. I have amended the question with more details including my stylesheet – the stylesheet is very basic and uses no SQL server specific functionality

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the error you receive? I'm curious what assembly and method are throwing it!

Comment: Thank you for amending the question -- that answers a lot of my questions!

Comment: @AnnL. I've added the stack trace to the post

Comment: Hi @Ecoliat is this already resolved? Or have you created a work around of this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information in the GitHub issue [.NET 6 not support `XslCompiledTransform.Load(type(myXsltCompiled_dll))`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68129), it looks as if this is not supported, and won't be.

A comment on April 18, 2022 said:

> The assembly `System.Data.SqlXml` contains the namespace `System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime`, which is not present in .NET Core.
>
> According to the porting guide, `msxsl:script` is unavailable on .NET Core. The .NET Framework specific tutorial is expected not to work.

A second person commented:

> Looks like `System.Data.SqlXml` is part of SQLXML which is owned by the
> SQL Server org and as far as I know does not support .NET Core.

A third person replied:

> There are currently no plans regarding SQLXML and support for .NET 5+,
> and we haven't heard many requests in this direction. I would
> recommend opening up a User Voice here to get some traction and
> consensus on the subject: https://aka.ms/sqlfeedback

So, that's your answer: "`msxsl:script` is unavailable on .NET Core. The .NET Framework specific tutorial is expected not to work." and the reason is that a non-.NET group would have to make it possible, but doesn't have plans to. They don't perceive a demand.

And, they acknowledge that the documentation is misleading. It appears that a change was made to the docs in May 2022, and a pull request created:  [Note that XSLT script blocks are .NET Framework only](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/29482).

**I recognize that this does not provide a solution or a way forward for you, and that is disappointing. But this is the answer to your question: doing a transform this way simply isn't supported in .NET 6.0.**

Answer (score 0):

Although it is about two years from this question I'd like to share workaround, that I've done for my purposes, because I didn't find any other solution, that helps using compiled XSLT dll in .NET Core based transformations.

So if you would like to use `XslCompiledTransform` class with dll types generated via `xlstc.exe` you follow these steps:

1. Generate dll class(es)

   `xsltc.exe /class:Transform /out:Your.Assembly.dll`
2. Disassembly your dll to ILL code

   `ildasm Your.Assembly.dll /out=Your.Assembly.ill`
3. Replace all occurences of [System.Data.SqlXml] with [System.Private.Xml] in Your.Assembly.ill
4. Compile you IL back to dll

   `ilasm Your.Assembly.ill /dll`
5. Now you can add `Your.Assembly.dll` reference to your .NET Core project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).